# How to add TextBlock inside MahApps Tile?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to add a TextBlock inside a MahApps Tile's title (having in mind binding portions of the text with some properties). I've tried this, but it says "Property does not support values of type TextBlock".

```
<mah:Tile> 
<mah:Tile.Title>                             
    <TextBlock>                           
    </TextBlock>                        
</mah:Tile.Title>
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Have you tries it after adding as a grid?

Comment: @Sumodh S It gives the same error, if I replace TextBlock with Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Title property of the Tile explicitly wants a String to be passed, so you can't link a TextBlock here.

You can now do the following:

- Overwrite the Template of the Tile: This gives you complete freedom of how to structure the appearance, but you may easily lose some of the behaviors of the Tile
- My recommendation: Leave the Title of the Tile blank and overwrite the ContentTemplate of the Tile to simply show your own Title TextBlock besides the main content of the Tile. In this case the viewmodel that you are binding to the tile could have a Body and a Title property and your xaml including datatemplate could look like:

With this you can also move the Title to any position you like

```
<mah:Tile DataContext="yourViewModel">
    <mah:Tile.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Body}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </mah:Tile.ContentTemplate> 
</mah:Tile>
```